# Does time-dependent perturbation theory work for time-independent perturbations?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hamiltonian, perturbation-theory, fermis-golden-rule

Are the results from time-dependent perturbation theory for time dependent Hamiltonians of the form $H = H_0 + \Delta H(t)$ (such as the result  below) equally valid for time independent Hamiltonians of the form $H = H_0 + \Delta H$, if the objective is to find how the eigenstates $|k_0\rangle$ of the unperturbed Hamiltonian $H_0$ evolve under time in the full Hamiltonian $H$?

$$P(i \rightarrow f) = \frac{1}{\hbar^2} |\langle f|\Delta H|i \rangle|^2 \frac{1}{\omega_{if}^2}. $$

Comment: You mean by just taking $\Delta H(t)$ to be a constant function?

Comment: Yes taking it to have no time dependence

Comment: How could it not work? Did you run into any kind of technical problem trying to do it?

Comment: I assumed it might work seeing as the TDPT derivation seems to use general principles, expanding in a certain basis, using the TDSE etc, but I wasn't sure and was wondering if it could be made obvious in the maths

Comment: Could you show us what you've tried?